# Remove Duplicate/Existing value from dropdownlist

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, html.dropdownlistfor

I will like to generate a dropdownlist with unique value.
However i only able to generate an original dropdownlist which generated from database.

At my language table it contain 3 languages:
-ENG , GER, KOR

for the language i already used for a question list:
- KOR

So the result bind to dropdownlist should:
- ENG, GER

My Controller code:

```
 List<SelectListItem> langResult = new List<SelectListItem>();

                    ///// Ori Language
                    var result = from r in db.SURV_Language_Model
                                  select r.Language; 

                    ///// Used Language
                    var result2 =   from r in db.SURV_Question_Ext_Model
                                    join s in db.SURV_Question_Model on r.Qext_Question_ID equals s.Question_ID
                                    orderby s.Question_Position ascending
                                    where r.Qext_Question_ID == Question_ID
                                    select new { r, s }; 

                    /////Remaining Language
                    result 3 =  result 2 - result 1 <==*** Pseudo code

                    foreach (var item in result3)
                    {
                        SelectListItem temp = new SelectListItem();
                        temp.Text = item;
                        temp.Value = item;
                        langResult.Add(temp);
                    }

                    ViewBag.LangList = langResult;
```

My View Code:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Language)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Language, ViewBag.LangList as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Language, "*")
```

Anyway to perform this?

Comment: wouldnt it be easier if you just clear the list before populating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was fixed by code below, hope can help you all:

```
List<SelectListItem> langResult = new List<SelectListItem>();

                var result = from r in db.SURV_Language_Model
                              select r.Language;

                var result2 =   from r in db.SURV_Question_Ext_Model
                                join s in db.SURV_Question_Model on r.Qext_Question_ID equals s.Question_ID
                                orderby s.Question_Position ascending
                                where r.Qext_Question_ID == Question_ID
                                select r.Qext_Language;


                List<string> list = new List<string>(result);
                List<string> list2 = new List<string>(result2);

                for (int x = 0; x < list.Count(); x++ )
                {             
                    if ( x < list2.Count())
                    { 
                       if (list[0].ToString() == list2[x].ToString())
                       {
                           list.Remove(list[0].ToString());
                       }
                    }       

                }

                foreach (var item in list)
                {
                    SelectListItem temp = new SelectListItem();
                    temp.Text = item;
                    temp.Value = item;
                    langResult.Add(temp);
                }

                ViewBag.LangList = langResult;
```